# Zoom Windows Meeting SDK: How minimize the meeting programatically?

Tags: c++, windows, zoom-sdk

I use Zoom Windows Meeting SDK v5.13.5.12103.
OS: Windows 10

Is there any method to minimize the meeting programatically?
Tried to use ShowWindow() with different nCmdShow but it doesn’t work.

By "minimize" I mean show the Zoom Mini Window (this is the thing that allows you to minimize the Zoom video, but keep it on top of any other applications you have open on your computer). It looks like with ShowWindow() I couldn't achieve this.

So I have two methods - show zoom conference window and hide it. When hidden, the mini window doesn't appear.

Looks like secondView isn't what I need either. The documentation isn't very detailed, but it seems to have something to do with displaying a window on a second monitor.

```
     bool FlutterZoomSdkPlugin::showMeeting() {
        if (FlutterZoomSdkPlugin::MeetingService) {
            ZOOM_SDK_NAMESPACE::IMeetingUIController* UIController = FlutterZoomSdkPlugin::MeetingService->GetUIController();

            if (UIController) {
                HWND firstView = NULL;
                HWND secondView = NULL;

                UIController->GetMeetingUIWnd(firstView, secondView);

                if (firstView) {
                    ShowWindow(firstView, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
                    UIController->BackToMeeting();

                    _cputts(L"Show meeting screen\n");

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool FlutterZoomSdkPlugin::hideMeeting() {
        if (FlutterZoomSdkPlugin::MeetingService) {
            ZOOM_SDK_NAMESPACE::IMeetingUIController* UIController = FlutterZoomSdkPlugin::MeetingService->GetUIController();

            if (UIController) {
                HWND firstView = NULL;
                HWND secondView = NULL;

                UIController->GetMeetingUIWnd(firstView, secondView);

                if (firstView) {
                    ShowWindow(firstView, SW_HIDE);

                    _cputts(L"Hide meeting screen\n");

                    return true;
                }

            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: whats the meaning of "doesn't work" ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number by "minimize" I mean show the Zoom Mini Window (this is the thing that allows you to minimize the Zoom video, but keep it on top of any other applications you have open on your computer). It looks like with ShowWindow() I couldn't achieve this

Comment: you should edit the question to add the missing details.

Comment: @kiner_shah You can take a demo project of the Zoom Windows Meeting SDK. It's on the Zoom App Marketplace

Comment: @M14, that's too much effort. Better to show what you have tried and where you face issues.